# A origem da palavra Obrigado em forma de agradecimento

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

A palavra **obrigado** em forma de agradecimento tem o mesmo fonema de **obrigatoriedade**. Estas duas palavras têm a mesma origem ou simplesmente foi o acaso que as deixou parecidas?

Esta dúvida me surgiu outro dia quando estava em um restaurante em Lisboa, quando o garçom me trouxe a minha comida e colocou na minha frente eu disse "Obrigado".

Ele, o garçom, prontamente respondeu: "O obrigado sou eu".

Quando questionei o que ele tinha dito, ele novamente, me disse: Sim eu sou obrigado a te trazer a comida. Devido ao mau humor do garçom resolvi comer minha comida que estava deliciosa e ficar a pensar no assunto sozinho.

Agora pergunto: porque dizemos "Obrigado" em forma de agradecimento, e qual a origem desta palavra?

Comment: Vou só deixar uma nota: "Garçon" vem do Francês e pode ser considerado má educação tanto por significar "rapaz" como por ser estrangeirismo. No geral, trata-se o funcionário na 3ª pessoa sem usar pronome - evitando dirigir-se a ele por título profissional (excepto se for o "sommelier" ou algum título assim...)

Comment: Eu nao tratei o Garcom por gargon quando estava falando com ele :) Mas sim, em algum paizes existe essa conotacao. Nao tem todos, nem em todas as linguas, possivelmente nem em todas as profissoes.

Answer (score 4):

Só acrescentando algo mais à excelente resposta já existente, dizemos "muito obrigado" na língua portuguesa como forma de agradecimento e expressando que **nos sentimos obrigados** a retribuir de alguma forma no futuro, embora na maioria das vezes isso seja dito só "da boca pra fora".  Coincidentemente, em Inglês temos a mesma expressão: [**"much obliged"**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152446/much-obliged-old-fashioned-polite-pedantic), usada com o mesmo significado e nas mesmas situações.

Comment: Esta resposta foi brilhante, nunca tinha pensado nestes 2 aspectos.

Answer (score 3):

> Agora pergunto: porque dizemos "Obrigado" em forma de agradecimento, e qual a origem desta palavra?

Em morfologia derivacional (e flexional), a **raiz** *"obrig"* admite toda uma séria de sufixos e prefixos -(**morfemas dependentes**). E.g. des-*obrig*-ar, *obrig*-a-ção, *obrig*-a-tório, *obrig*-a-tor-ie-dade, etc...Não tenho aqui o dicionário etimológico, por isso não sei, mas acho que a origem exata da **raiz** *"obrig"* é controversa...

> tem o mesmo fonema

Repara bem que a **raiz** *"obrig"* tem vários **fonemas** -  [ver alfabeto fonético](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_Fon%C3%A9tico_Internacional). Eu não tenho a certeza se (acho que não) pode ser subdividida em morfemas - nisto até autores de linguística por vezes discordam.

> Ele, o garçom, prontamente respondeu: "O obrigado sou eu".
>
> Sim eu sou obrigado a te trazer a comida.

O que o "servente de mesa" (termo correto -anacrónico- que hoje é evitado) fez foi um trocadilho, muito comum, sobre a homonímia do "obrigado". Cujo duplo sentido contraditório coincide na perfeição, pela oposição entre o adjectivo "ser obrigado" e o substantivo "grato". Obrigado, obrigadinho...

O reparo do "funcionário da [**restauração**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restaura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_Independ%C3%AAncia)" (termo moderno) costuma ter por acessório a expressão:"o Português é muito traiçoeiro". O que não se refere ao "povo dos brandos costumes" mas precisamente às coincidências (que são tudo, menos acaso) de duplos sentidos por sobreposições de semântica num mesmo vocábulo. Do qual, o "obrigado" é exemplo.

O que o funcionário disse foi uma piada, e sugere que às tantas preferia estar noutro lugar a fazer outra coisa, mas tinha de estar ali, a trabalhar...

(Como eu o entendo.)

> '«Obrigado» virá do particípio passado do verbo latino «obligō». Este, se escavarmos um pouco, veio da raiz indo-europeia «*leyǵ-», que significaria ligar — e, diga-se, o verbo português «ligar» tem a mesmíssima origem indo-europeia.
>
> Isto é interessante, não tenho dúvidas, mas mais interessante será ver que esta viagem não explica a origem da nossa fórmula de agradecimento. Afinal, a origem que descrevi acima é a mesmíssima origem da palavra «obligado» do castelhano — e um espanhol nunca diz «obligado» para agradecer seja o que for.'

in Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa, https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/qual-e-a-origem-da-palavra-obrigado/3725 [consultado em 03-04-2020]

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado vem do latim obligare = ligar por todos os lados, ligar moralmente; a expressão originalmente era Ficar obrigado, ou seja, ficar ligado por um laço moral, que com o tempo reduziu-se a Obrigado, praticamente uma interjeição :)