# Por que agradecemos com "obrigado"?

Tags: etimologia

minha pergunta se dá pelo fato de ter notado que tanto o espanhol (gracias) quanto o italiano (grazie) tem suas formas de agradecer derivadas diretamente do latim culto (gratias), porém no português utilizamos uma forma muito distinta, essa forma deriva de alguma outra construção do latim que desconheço? há alguma razão histórica para isso?

Comment: Seja bem vindo @Fabricio_A, esta pergunta já feita aqui na comunidade reponderia sua dúvida? https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/a-origem-da-palavra-obrigado-em-forma-de-agradecimento